# Required permissions cannot be acquired error when hosting web site

Tags: asp.net

A client has sent me their web site and I got it to work on my local machine, but after hosting it on my website under a sub domain I get the following error:

```
Required permissions cannot be acquired.
```

I did some searching and tried messing with the trust tag in web.config, but then that told me:

*This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  from an inherited configuration file.*

I have looked through the location settings in the web.config and don't see anything strange. What should I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the machine.config to see if something there is blocking you...

[see this](http://geekswithblogs.net/technetbytes/archive/2007/04/11/111370.aspx)

Basically you are looking for this...

```
<location allowOverride="false">
```

If you see that in the machine config that is wrapping the same section you are trying to edit in a web.config you will get that error.

Comment: following the directions in that link give me a `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: probably because it is setup for .net (OLD VERSION)... the point is just that you need to go look in the machine.config  
typically at 
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{version}\config\machine.config  if the override is set to false ... set it to true.